# Do I need Intel HD Graphics Driver?

Tags: windows-7, intel-graphics

Do I need Intel HD Graphics Driver installed on my PC?

This program was installed from the store when I installed windows 7. I didn't tell them to install it.

This is a huge file (74MB) to my PC since it only has 2GB memory. My PC is very slow now since I installed avast Internet Security, but I want a room for Avast.

So will uninstalling Intel HD Graphics driver cause me trouble?

PC Specs: Windows 7 64 bit SP1. I use Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: It is not the case that your computer has 2 MB of memory. Perhaps you mean 2 GB?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Yes, you are correct. I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Intel HD Graphics Driver is responsible for running your graphics, aka your display. Without it, your screen would be black and you would never be able to see anything. If you did uninstall it, it might use the standard VGA adapter driver, which would still take up some space but your resolution would be terrible. All of your icons would be huge and stuff would look bad.

I'm not sure what size hard drive you have because 2 MB of memory doesn't make any sense. Maybe you meant 2 GB of RAM but I'm not sure. If you want, post a link to a picture of how full your hard drive is. Like this:[image]

Comment: I am completely satisfied ur answer--that's the knowledge I wanted. As for ur request, I cant post  a photo --I hve only one rep

Comment: @knowledgeBlocker You should still be able to post us a **link** to a photo you uploaded on a third party site, like Imgur. I'm not 100% sure about that, but I'm pretty sure you can.

Comment: I just heard on this idea u  just gave me . let me try.

Comment: [here is the link] (http://imgur.com/aBNu610)

Comment: sorry for for bad link format ,that's not what I intended.

Comment: @knowledgeBlocker you still have a decent amount of space on C: drive and a ton of space on D: drive. So the Intel HD drivers aren't hurting you for space. I think you were thinking of 2 GB RAM which is used by programs that are currently running.

Comment: @knowledgeBlocker I got the link figured out. I saw the bad character. For future reference to link works to a URL use [word](URL)

Comment: ya, I am concerning about my 2GB ram. [check this out](http://i.imgur.com/b48NpML.png) to view my RAM usage

Comment: @knowledgeBlocker yeah that's a bit on the high side. You could always add more RAM to your system. It's a very easy fix

Comment: But I use an old pc, Aspire E1-431(Acer)

Comment: @knowledgeBlocker that laptop can have a maximum of 8 GB of RAM. It shows that the standard is usually 4 GB, but for whatever reason yours has 2 GB. [Tech specs](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1264550/acer-aspire-e1-431-20204g75mnrr-notebook.html)

Comment: u mean 2 ram of 4GB per slot ( = total of 8GB)?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the way you asked the question you aren't familiar with how "memory" works.

Your software is installed on a hard drive. Any more hard drives (Drive C: and possibly D:) will have plenty of space for lots of programs. So if the HD Graphics driver is taking up 78MB that's not a big deal. Avast takes up 400MB of space.

After installing Avast however, you will probably notice a slow down. Mainly because all software also needs RAM to run, that's your 2GB. The HD Drivers might be using 50MB of that Avast about 128MB. Windows probably 1GB. And that's when Avast is passively sitting there. If you scan it's memory require could eaisly double.

The more programs you run the more RAM you need. Any more ?I would recommend 4GB minimum. If you have a tablet, you're kind of out of luck. There isn't a way to upgrade tablet memory like there is in most laptops and desktops.

Comment: thanx that's a great info which I didn't knew before.